# how to add a button click event in a custom element

Tags: javascript, webpack, lit-element

I want to add a click event to the button with id: hamb-btn, where when clicked it will add a new class in the div class = "nav-link show" element. like that is an example of adding the class if the hamb button is pressed.
its my code...
note: i use webpack.

```js
import { html, css, LitElement } from 'lit-element';

class SinDrawer extends LitElement {
    static get styles() {
        return css`
            nav {
                display: flex;
                padding: 8px;
                background-color: var(--main-color);
            }
        `;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <nav>
                <div class="nav-brand">
                    <a href="#/home">
                        <img src="./icons/icon_512.png" alt="sr-brand" height="50" title="Sinfor-Resto">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#/home" class="nav-anchor">Beranda</a>
                    <a href="#/favorite" class="nav-anchor">Favorite</a>
                    <a href="#/about" class="nav-anchor">Tentang</a>
                </div>
                <button id="hamb-btn" onclick="">&#9776;</button>
            </nav>
        `;
    }
}

customElements.define('sin-drawer', SinDrawer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `classMap` or `styleMap` directives for the dynamic styling in the Lit Component. More information available at [Dynamic classes and styles](https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/#dynamic-classes-and-styles).

```js
import { html, css, LitElement } from 'lit-element';
import { classMap } from 'lit/directives/class-map.js';

class SinDrawer extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      nav {
        display: flex;
        padding: 8px;
        background-color: var(--main-color);
      }
    `;
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      _show: { state: true },
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._show = false;
  }

  show() {
    this._show = !this._show;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-brand">
          <a href="#/home">
            <img src="./icons/icon_512.png" alt="sr-brand" height="50" title="Sinfor-Resto" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-link ${classMap({ show: this._show })}">
          <a href="#/home" class="nav-anchor">Beranda</a>
          <a href="#/favorite" class="nav-anchor">Favorite</a>
          <a href="#/about" class="nav-anchor">Tentang</a>
        </div>
        <button id="hamb-btn" @click=${this.show}>&#9776;</button>
      </nav>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('sin-drawer', SinDrawer);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 3 simple steps.

1. Add a property ‘newClass’ as follows and initialise this.newClass as “” in constructor.

```
     static get properties(){
        return{
             newClass: String
            }
        }
```

2. Add ‘newClass’ to the div as follows

```
 <div class="nav-link ${this.newClass}">
```

3. On click of the button, this.newClass will contain the new class name.

```
<button id="hamb-btn" @click=${e=>this.newClass =”newClassName”}>&#9776;</button>
```

Since this.newClass is added to properties of the element, it will rerender the DOM and update the div with class=”nav-link newClassName”